# How can I disable Auto-Sign on my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

Currently if I sign out of the Facebook app, sign in requires only that I press on my name. There is no password required.  How can I change this? I'd like to have to type in my password each time to login to the Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

If the app does not support it, you cannot change it.  I would recommend that you use an app locker.  I have always used one.  There are many around.  I currently use Kaspersky for anti-virus and it has this feature.  There are free ones around too.

- After installation, you select which apps require more security.
- You select what sort of security you want, I use a 6 digit pin or a fingerprint.
- When you press on the app icon, the AppLocker will pop up and you can enter your pin or whatever.

I lock all my sensitive apps this way, this includes Banking, Social, Email,  Internet (browsers etc), and Play Store (so no one else can install another app).

Comment: Is there no way to completely sign out? There used to be a checkbox you could check or uncheck to select "Keep me logged in" (at least on the web version of FB)